# Xcode crashes on throwing fatalError

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

```
static func saveContext (context: NSManagedObjectContext = getContext()) {        
    if context.hasChanges {        
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let nserror as NSError {      
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

(I throw it on saving CoreData context)

When I throw fatalError Xcode itself crashes every time and I have to open it again.

Maybe someone knows how to fix it or smth?

Comment: Whats the error reported in the console?

Comment: I have breakpoints directly on fatalError line. Otherwise whole xcode just crashes before I can read the error.

Comment: so whats the error you are getting mate? we aren't mind readers, I cant just guess what the issue might be from 'its crashing when it starts on this line'. have you changed the db structure recently? have you removed form delive and re-installed?

Comment: @Scriptable I'm seeing this too. Xcode abends pretty much instantly when the app hits this, so it's pretty difficult to read the console without changing `fatalError` to `NSLog`. Note that changing the code to `fatalError("Unresolved data error.")` — i.e. without including the error in the string — helps keep Xcode working.